# Validate MySQL username and password

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

Is it possible to validate the given MySQL username and password using shell script without attempting to login to the MySQL service? If so, How? I haven't found any useful solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It works.

```
mysql -u$USER_NAME  -p$PASSWORD -eexit
```

If you provide correct login credentials, the exit code will be 0 else it will be 1.

Example:

```
miyurz@my-host:~$ mysql -uroot  -pabc123 -eexit
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

```
miyurz@my-host:~$ echo $?
1
---------------------------------------------------

miyurz@my-host:~$ mysql -uroot  -pabc12 -eexit

miyurz@my-host:~$ echo $?
0
```

Explanation:

```
-e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit.
```

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't believe this is possible.

You would need to attempt to connect to MySQL in order to validate if the authentication details are correct.  Even to query the MySQL user table directly (where credentials are stored) would require making a connection to the MySQL server.

Perhaps you can share why you would need to do this?

Comment: `Perhaps you can share why you would need to do this` see: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Comment: I agree with you. My task is to automate the MySQL login in a shell script and to do that I need to validate the given user-password. Is there any other way you can suggest? All I want to do is only check if the user-password are valid. At this point of time, I don't have any queries to run

Comment: It sounds like you can connect to MySQL, but you just don't have a query to run. Did you try just calling MySQL in your script with the username and password specified and assess the result? For example "mysql -Uusername -Ppassword". It should let you know if the supplied credentials are no good.